# Compare with a null pointer stills is constexpr in g++ 8.1.0

Tags: c++

This code compiles without any warnings in g++ 8.1.0:

```cpp
int main()
{
    constexpr int *a{nullptr};
    constexpr int b{};
    static_assert(a <= &b);
}
```

I thought that comparing with a null pointer gives an unspecified value, and an unspecified value cannot be `constexpr`.

But the code compiles fine in g++ 8.1.0, so why do it compiles?

Comment: gcc bug. [clang reports the correct diagnostic.](https://godbolt.org/z/755odfKfP)